# How can I stop a user from creating opportunity for a certain account

Tags: account, process

There are accounts that was tagged as out of scope and need not to be used in an opportunity.

But we cannot set this as inactive since we still have remaining transactions.

Comment: Based on that tagged field create validation rule.

Comment: Can you provide us more information what you have tried till now and where are you getting the error, what is the datatype of out of scope field and how are you identifying that account is tagged as out of scope? Have you tried using the Validation rule on Opportunity?

Comment: Hi @AmitSingh, I am still new in Salesforce so please bear with me. I am trying to use    a custom field in accounts (Checkbox) where i wanted to check if what are the best option if i will use it as reference or directly use the account IDs. i couldn't find a good idea how to do this in help and training.

Comment: Using a Checkbox on the Account Object will be the best option and display Error on Opportunity Creation if that checkbox field is True. You will find the validation rule on answer section

Answer (score 2):

You can have lookup filter for Account lookup on opportunity in such a way that those accounts are not allowed to select while creating opportunities. Lookup filter can be either on record type or name or any other field.

Comment: Hi @rashmi, thank you for this. I will try to use the suggested information. :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a Checkbox field On the Account Say it **Out Of Scope**

> Solution: - create a Validation Rule on Opportunity.

```
AND(
  NOT(ISBLANK(AccountId)),
  Account.Out_of_Scope__c
)
```

Display the Error that Opportunity Can not be created on Out of Scope Account.